# Formulário de contato com AJAX sem refresh

Tags: php, ajax

Como criar um formulário com ajax que ao pressionar o botão de enviar ele não te redirecione para uma outra página mas sim uma mensagem logo abaixo de "Dados enviados".

Segue um exemplo de código que estou estudando, porém este te redireciona para uma outra página no caso **sendemail.php**.

### **index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendemail.php">

            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /> </br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /> </br>
            Assunto: <input type="text" name="assunto" /> </br>
            Menssagem: <textarea name="menssagem"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Menssagem" />

        </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

---

### **sendemail.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$menssagem = $_POST['menssagem'];


?>

<?php 

$to = "teste@gmail.com";
$subject = "$assunto";
$menssagem = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br /><br /><strong>E-mail:</strong>$email<br /><br /><strong>Assunto:</strong> $assunto<br /><br /><strong>Menssagem:</strong> $menssagem ";
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $email\n";
mail($to, $subject, $menssagem,$header);
echo "Enviado!";

?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer, tirei o `name` que tinhas no form e coloquei `id`:

HTML:

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="sendemail.php">

        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /> </br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /> </br>
        Assunto: <input type="text" name="assunto" /> </br>
        Menssagem: <textarea name="menssagem"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar Menssagem" />
       <div id="resp"></div>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nome = $('input[name="nome"]').val();
    const email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
    const assunto = $('input[name="assunto"]').val();
    const mensagem = $('textarea[name="mensagem"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'sendemail.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
        type: 'POST',
        data: {nome: nome, email: email, assunto: assunto, mensagem: mensagem},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#resp').html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: uma alternativa interessante e aumenta um pouco mais a produtividade seria usar o método do jquery "Serializer()", ele captura todos os campos do seu forme e abstrai a declaração/chamada dos campos na função no método submit().

veja a documentação, é bem simples o uso http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Obrigado @LeandroMacedo , por acaso nunca usei esse metodo, como é que ele constroí a variável `data`?

Comment: Nesse caso irá remover a variáveis "nome","email", etc 
e em data deve ficar algo parecido com isso:

data: { $("#contactform").serializer() },

e no seu php vc recebe os campos pelo nome q atribuiu no form

Comment: Ha boa, não sabia, estou farto de ver mas na verdade nunca usei. Obagdo @LeandroMacedo

Comment: haha. De nada imagina

Answer (score 2):

Você pode só mudar colocar o target no form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendemail.php" target="local_onde_sera_exibido_a_msg">

        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /> </br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /> </br>
        Assunto: <input type="text" name="assunto" /> </br>
        Menssagem: <textarea name="menssagem"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar Menssagem" />
    </form>
    <iframe id="local_onde_sera_exibido_a_msg"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Para fazer algo realmente em AJAX você vai precisar fazer isso em Javascript buscando na web vc acha [isto (com JS puro)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) e [aquilo (com jquery)](http://www.webmaster.pt/requisicoes-ajax-jquery-2216.html)

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso. Precisa só incluir o arquivo jquery, caso ainda não use.

```
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendemail.php">

        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /> </br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /> </br>
        Assunto: <input type="text" name="assunto" /> </br>
        Menssagem: <textarea name="menssagem"></textarea>

        <input type="button" value="Enviar Menssagem" id="enviar" />

    </form>
    <script>
       $("#enviar").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           dataType:'html',
           url:"sendemai.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:({mensagem:$("input[name='nome']").val(),email:$("input[name='email']").val(),assunto:$("input[name='assunto']").val(),mensagem:$("input[name='mensagem']").val()}),

           beforeSend: function(data){ 

            }, success:function(data){
                alert("Dados Enviados");
            }, complete: function(data){}


           });
            });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**sendemail.php**

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$menssagem = $_POST['menssagem'];


$to = "teste@gmail.com";
$subject = "$assunto";
$menssagem = "<strong>Nome:</strong> $nome<br /><br /><strong>E-mail:</strong>$email<br /><br /><strong>Assunto:</strong> $assunto<br /><br /><strong>Menssagem:</strong> $menssagem ";
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $email\n";
mail($to, $subject, $menssagem,$header);
echo "Enviado!";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No php
 // no head

JS com Jquery
script.js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#Form_ws').submit(function(){
        carregando(1);
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "sendemail.php",
            data: dados,
...

serialize pega os campos do form e transforma em uma string get variavel&variavel
O sendemail.php recebe os parâmetros por GET