# Retornar saídas do PHP na mesma página

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

Tenho um `form` que é validado via JavaScript. Está funcionando perfeitamente, ele valida, manda pro `.php` e ele me da um `echo` dizendo que foi com sucesso. Porém eu queria que esse `echo` fosse dado na mesma página, como um `alert`, ou então mudar o display de uma `div` já existente. Como eu trago essa saída do PHP pra mesma página? Eu vi que deveria usar Ajax, mas não entendi muito bem, não sei o que faz o que no código AJAX.

Código PHP:

```
<?php
$pergunta = $_POST ['pergunta'];
$resposta = $_POST ['resposta'];
$dificuldade = $_POST ['dificuldade'];
$desafio = $_POST ['desafio'];

switch ($dificuldade) {
  case '1':
    $dificuldade = "Facil";
    break;
  case '2':
    $dificuldade = "Medio";
    break;
  case '2':
    $dificuldade = "Dificil";
    break;
}

try{
 $conexao = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;       dbname=teocratico;charset=utf8","root","");
 } catch (PDOException $erro){
   echo "Não foi possível conectar ao banco ". $erro->getMessage();

 }

try {
 $insert =  $conexao-> prepare ("INSERT INTO perguntas (pergunta, resposta,         dificuldade, desafio) VALUES (

       :pergunta,
       :resposta,
       :dificuldade,
       :desafio
        )");
  $insert-> bindParam (':pergunta', $pergunta);
  $insert-> bindParam (':resposta', $resposta);
  $insert-> bindParam (':dificuldade', $dificuldade);
  $insert-> bindParam (':desafio', $desafio);
  $insert-> execute();
  echo "Pergunta enviada com Sucesso";
} catch (Exception $erro) {
 echo "Não foi possivel enviar os dados" . $erro->getMessage();

}
?>
```

Código Ajax:

```
  $('#form_pergunta').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const pergunta = $('input[name="pergunta"]').val();
   const resposta = $('input[name="resposta"]').val();
   const dificuldade = $('input[name="dificuldade"]')
   const desafio = $('select[name="desafio"]').val();

   $.ajax({
       url: 'envia.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
   type: 'POST',
   data: {pergunta: pergunta, resposta: resposta, dificuldade: dificuldade,    desafio: desafio},
       success: function(response) {
           $('#resp').php(response);
       },
       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
           alert(xhr.responseText);
       }
    });
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Ve se esse link lhe ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174883/formul%C3%A1rio-de-contato-com-ajax-sem-refresh

Comment: Se não quiser ajax, pode simplesmente colocar o script que recebe o form na mesma página.
No topo da página tu põe uma verificação pra saber se houve o POST.
if( (isset($_POST['nome'])) and (!empty($_POST['nome']))){
// executa a função de recebimento e gravação dos dados ou envio de e-mail
// se der tudo certo
echo "<div>deu certo</div>";
}

Comment: Tiago, se possível de uma pesquisada rápida em "jQuery Ajax via Load", cara é bem simples usar em resumo o comando é $("#div_resultado").load("codigo.php", {"nome_dado1": dado1, "nome_dado2": dado2}); os dados são enviados para o PHP no próprio load e na div_resultado o echo será retornado com o resultado.

Answer (score 3):

**O que é ajax?**

Basicamente, ajax é quando você faz uma chamada a um script ( não importa se é php, json, asp, javascript, html ). Essa chamada, faz com que o javascript busque um arquivo no servidor, que você irá específicar qual é, nesse caso, é o *retornaDados.php*, exemplo:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("retornaDados.php", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data );
    });
});
```

Por favor, perceba duas coisas.

Primeiro, o *retornaDados.php*, que é o arquivos que nós chamamos no servidor através do javascript ( no exemplo usei jquery, para que você entenda melhor ).

Segunda, o Jquery irá retornar uma **data**. Essa data é a saída do seu arquivo php. Vamos usar um exemplo simples de php. Esse é o arquivo *retornaDados.php*

```
$a = 2
$b = 3
echo $a + $b;
```

Como você pode ver, irá retornar 5 naquela varável **data** do Jquery.

**Enviando dados para o PHP**

No seu código, você utilizou $.ajax, mas é recomendado tratar diretamente no $.post ( em outros casos, $.get).

Segue um exemplo de como ficaria utilizando $.post

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
    });
});
```

Perceba as linhas:

```
        $.post("retornaDados.php",
    {
        nome: "Felipe",
        cidade: "Verdelandia"
    },
```

depois da vírgula que requisita o *retornaDados.php*, você pode (opcionalmente) colocar os dados que serã enviados para o *retornaDados.php*. Neste caso, nome e cidade serão enviados para o php usando os valores "Felipe" E "Verdelandia" respectivamente.

Perceba como ficou o php agora. Lembrando que *$_['POST']* e *$_['GET']* devem ser utilizados de acordo com o envio! Seja ele *$.post* ou *$.get*

```
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$cidade = $_POST["cidade"] ;
echo $nome . " mora na cidade de " . $cidade;
```

Explicando novamente, o método $_POST["variavel do jquery"] irá recuperar dados enviando através de POST e colocar em uma variável, mas pode ser utilizado diretamente.

```
echo $_POST["nome"] . " mora na cidade de " . $_POST["cidade"]
```

Comment: Acho que entendi mais ou menos, vou colocar o código na pergunta.

Comment: Recomendo não colocar o código "para ser feito", eu pessoalmene não me importo em ajudar, mas os outros usuários do Stackoverflow podem te negativar e eu não poderei ajudar mais.

Comment: Ata, eu fiz o Código Ajax, igual a pergunta do comentário do colega acima, mas não funcionou :/

Comment: Eu já uso o evento onclick para os dados serem validados por outro arquivo js.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira eu comendo que você utilize $.get ou $.post, no seu caso você escolheu POST. Eu vou editar pra mostrar como é o envio de dados através do POST.

Comment: Tudo bem, @asurakhan, vou aguardar.

Comment: Pronto, vê se isso responde a sua dúvida.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51363/discussion-between-tiago-silveira-and-asura-khan).

Comment: Eu não compreendi, por que eu só quero que quando os dados forem enviados com sucesso pelo php, ele me de um alert, só isso. Não entendi muito bem a forma que você fez. outra coisa, eu posso disparar 2 funções com o mesmo evento, no caso o onclick.

Comment: você pode colocar um javascript no php echo "<script> alert("enviado") </script>". Essas funções dentro do onClick, são os callback. São pequenas funções que retornam ou fazem algo dentro de uma função.

Comment: Olha o chat, por favor @asurakhan