# formulario esta com problema ao recuperar o value do Post

Tags: php, javascript, html5, lógica

ola estou fazendo um site e queria assim que a pessoa digita-se o link o javascript pegasse e enviasse o formulário porem ele esta enviando mas quando tento recuperar com o $_POST ele n recupera o valor q foi enviado código q estou usando.

```
<?php echo $_POST['link'] ; ?>
<form name="form" action="" method="POST" id="meuForm" name="meuForm">
      <input type="txt" name="link" id="link" class="form-control form-control-lg"  placeholder="Link Para Encurtar"  onkeydown="myFunction()">

</form>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        meuForm.submit(); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: mas vai enviar pra mesma página?

Comment: sim por isso deixei o action vazio, funciona igual eu colocar action="#" ela envia para mesma pagina , e por isso tem o <?php echo $_POST['link']; ?> para q quando envie ele receba e mostre o value q esta no input

Comment: tira o action="", deixa sem e pode apagar o script q vai funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione como desejado tem que usar  `onblur="myFunction()"`

Dessa forma a função é chamada quando clicar fora do `input`

> Se usar `onkeydown` a função é disparada assim que a tecla é pressionada, portanto não dá tempo de passar nada.

### Usando `crt+v` ou `digitando` use `jquery`

**biblioteca**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**

```
$("#link").on("paste change", function () {
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#meuForm').trigger('submit')
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php echo $_POST['link'] ; ?>
<form name="form" action="" method="POST" id="meuForm" name="meuForm">
<input type="txt" name="link" id="link" class="form-control form-control-lg"  placeholder="Link Para Encurtar">
</form>
```

> OBS: `change` vai funcionar como se fosse `blur`. Tem que digitar e depois clicar fora do input. Já com `crt+v` a função dispara automaticamente ao colar o texto no input.

Comment: pensei em usar o onblur mas infelismente n atende meu requisito

Comment: @romulohenrique, quais requisitos?

Comment: exemplo se a pessoa acabar de clicar crt+v para color o texto assim ela envia

Comment: ou quando ela digitace A ai ela enviasse a letra A direto sem a pesso precisar clicar fora do input

Comment: @romulohenrique, então pra que serve o input `ENCURTAR` ?

Comment: com ja expliquei em um dos comentarios foi errado do codigo antigo eu ate editei e direi de la,

Answer (score 1):

Pra enviar o formulário pra mesma pagina não há necessidade de ter o atributo `action`, consequentemente, o `<script>` tbm não:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){
        echo $_POST['link'];
    } 
?>
<form name="form" method="POST" id="meuForm" name="meuForm">
      <input type="txt" name="link" id="link" class="form-control form-control-lg"  placeholder="Link Para Encurtar"  onkeydown="myFunction()">
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" value="ENCURTAR"> 
</form>
```

Comment: eu usei o script para q o fomulario seja enviado altomaticamente então sera nescesario

Comment: o botão q foi sem querer que copie o codigo antigo ai ainda tinha o botão

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi, vc quer q ele seja enviado dinamicamente?

Comment: sim, automaticamente  por isso coloquei o javascript com "     meuForm.submit(); " para ele fazer o submit asim q a função for chamada

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175896/retornar-sa%C3%ADdas-do-php-na-mesma-p%C3%A1gina,